# If my screen Size is 480x800 what screen size should i choose in photoshop for android UI design

Tags: android

I am a bit confused in designing the layout for my app.
My main problem is that whatever I am designing should not look too small or get clipped.

What screen resolution to choose in psd for 480x800

Comment: Unfortunatelly the answer is not a simple one line reply. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose exacly they created [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) page. The problem here is not only the devices resolutions, but also those here:

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

You will also have to take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Designing an App is not a simple matter if you would like it to look "the same" on different devices, those are devises with different screen sizes and/or densities.

**EDIT:**

You may also like to take a look at this like [here](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/understanding-density-independence-android), which explains, as stated on the title "Understanding Density Independence in Android".

Cheers