# icons seems too small in some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

My icon size: 32x32 for mdpi, 48x48 for hdpi and 64x64 for xhdpi. in some devices are everything ok. But others... Code as shown below

```
                    bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.on_green_icon);   
                    int w = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
                    int h = bmpOriginal.getHeight();

                    Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
                    tempCanvas.rotate(f, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
                    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
                    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bmResult);
                LayerDrawable finalImage = new LayerDrawable(
                             new Drawable[]{bmd, new BitmapDrawable(bmResult)}); 
                            itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6), str_info, editDate, finalImage);
```

Comment: you need to put 96x96 icon in your drawable resourse...

Comment: I put my answer below, because anyone show your question that get answer in this question. sometime someone not read comments so, they get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put **96x96** icon in your **drawable resourse**.

because that is the size which can be prefer to many **device resolutions**.

so, that is works...

try to put and see result.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in the reply I've just given about all that, check the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417928/if-my-screen-size-is-480x800-what-screen-size-should-i-choose-in-photoshop-for-a/17418089#17418089). It's a more complete information about the whole process, as well as the link the Gru provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand first the what size of images required for particular `density bucket`
 i.e. MDPI, HDPI or XDPI etc.

Following link give you idea about that.

[Have look at this link](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/understanding-density-independence-android)